# JQuery: Why is my recursive animation not terminating on a call to stop?

Tags: jquery

Here is my code

```
<div class="MenuButton" 
     onmouseenter="$(function pulse(){
         $('#menuManage').delay(50).animate({
             opacity:0.25, height:'+=10px'
         }).delay(50).animate({
             opacity:1.00, height:'-=10px'
         },pulse);
     })"
     onmouseleave="$(function(){
         $('#menuManage').stop(true, true);};)" 
     id="menuManage">
```

The pulsating effect starts on mouse enter but does not stop on mouse leave.

What is going on?

Comment: Why are you wrapping code in an onevent in a domready handler?

Comment: I've just started playing around with JQuery, so I cannot understand what you said, but it would be great to know what you are suggesting exactly.

Comment: This is an onDomReady handler: `$(function(){...})` it executes the function passed to it when the dom is ready. Since you're using an onEvent, there's no need to wait for the dom to be ready because it will be.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in the mouseleave handler, change

```
$(function(){
    $('#menuManage').stop(true, true);
};)
```

to

```
$(function(){
   $('#menuManage').stop(true, true);
});
```

better yet, remove the inline javascript